# Pattern matching warning

Tags: f#

I am using patternmatching within a function as follows  :

```
let rec calculate   : Calculation<MyType> -> MyVO -> Calculation<MyType list>=
    fun c l ->
        fun arrayA arrayC ->
        myComputationExpression {
            if arrayA.Length<>arrayC.Length then 
                yield! l
            else
                match arrayA, arrayC with
                | [], [] -> yield! C
                | [a], [c] -> yield! calculate a c
                | headA :: tailA, headC :: tailC -> 
                    yield! calculateOpenAny headA headC
                    yield! calculate c l tailA tailC
        }
```

I have the following warning :

> Fsc: C:\myfile.fs(17,27): warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '( _ , [_] )' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).

I quite don't get it because, it should not happen becuse of the first conditionnal statement :

```
if arrayA.Length<>arrayC.Length then
```

Is there something I am missing here, or could I overlook the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler is not all-seeing. It can prove *some* things, but it cannot analyse your program fully, paying attention to semantics, like a human could.

In particular, the compiler doesn't know the relationship between the value of property `.Length` and the shape of the list (i.e. whether it's empty or not). From the compiler's point of view, `Length` is just a random property, you might as well have compared the results of `.ToString()` calls.

A better way to go about this would be incorporating different-lengths case in the pattern match:

```
let rec calculate   : Calculation<MyType> -> MyVO -> Calculation<MyType list>=
    fun c l ->
        fun arrayA arrayC ->
        myComputationExpression {
            match arrayA, arrayC with
            | [], [] -> yield! C
            | [a], [c] -> yield! calculate a c
            | headA :: tailA, headC :: tailC -> 
                yield! calculateOpenAny headA headC
                yield! calculate c l tailA tailC
            | _, _ -> yield! l
        }
```

An additional bonus here would be performance: computing length of a list is actually an O(n) operation, so you'd do better by avoiding it.

---

On an unrelated note, keep in mind that all of these are equivalent:

```
fun a -> fun b -> fun c -> ...
fun a -> fun b c -> ...
fun a b -> fun c -> ...
fun a b c -> ...
```

This is because of how parameters work in F# (and in all of ML family): functions take parameters "one by one", not all at once, at each step returning another function that "expects" the rest of parameters. This is called "[currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)". Functions in F# are *curried* by default.

In your case this means that your function could be declared shorter like this:

```
let rec calculate =
    fun c l arrayA arrayC ->
        ...
```

Or even shorter like this:

```
let rec calculate c l arrayA arrayC =
   ...
```

Comment: Thx a lot. At first, I was involving the length like you described but I thought it would be better performance-wise to iter through the list only if the two lists had the same length. What you tell me is that I should better avoid it and that performance should be better with the length in the pattern matching, it is interesting.
 As for the currying, I use the two functions like that only for aesthetics, but maybe this is not what is expected by functional folks, I am really much a learner for now. 
Thanks your lengthy answer. It really helps.

Comment: To clarify: there is no length in the pattern matching. In my code the length is never computed.

Comment: Actually it is partially done because you go through the rec to iterate over the whole list until you are at the end. For instance with two lists of 10 and 11 items; we would recursively enter the first element, then the second and so on, until the tenth where pattern matching will deduce to go through the last case.

Comment: Ok I got what you said. using length would make me iterate through the list twice.

Comment: Not twice, but actually N+1 times (in case both lists are of the same length N)